# Making JS buttons that toggle their image on click

Tags: javascript, button, toggle

I am doing something like this-

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop

but I want to replace the buttons with images that toggle to another image when clicked. In other words, the Play button will change to a Pause button.

There are many tutorials that show how to do this with only one button but as soon as I add more buttons, the new ones don't work.

Any help appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>


<script type="text/javascript">

function changeIt()
{
var theImg = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;

var x = theImg.split("/");
var t = x.length-1;
var y = x[t];

if(y=='btnPlay.gif')
{
document.images.PlayOrPause.src='btnPause.gif'
}
if(y=='btnPause.gif')
{
document.images.PlayOrPause.src='btnPlay.gif'
}



}

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="changeIt()"><img src='btnPause.gif' name='PlayOrPause' border='0' /></a>
```

Comment: Can you please post some of your existing attempts for us to help you refine? SO is not for asking people to do your work for you, but we'd sure love to help you when you're truly stuck.

Comment: use the onClick function on your images.

Comment: I updated my post with one of my attempts. I didn't include this before because I know there are many ways to achieve this effect and I don't know what method is best. The above example works but there is only one button. If I want to have several buttons, only one of them works at a time. This is where my problem lies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this using input type image

**HTML**

```
<input type="image" src="play.png" class="play" onclick="toggle(this);"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.play, .pause {width:100px;height:100px;}
```

​

**JS**

```
function toggle(el){
    if(el.className!="pause")
    {
        el.src='pause.png';
        el.className="pause";
    }
    else if(el.className=="pause")
    {
        el.src='play.png';
        el.className="play";
    }

    return false;
}  ​
```

**A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JPWCQ/3/)**.
​

Comment: Fantastic! Now, if I actually wanted to have the button control a video, would I just add this here? onclick="toggle(this); "playPause()" />

Comment: Sorry, that should be inside your toogle function, like http://jsfiddle.net/JPWCQ/4/.

Comment: If you face any problem then please let me know, you asked only about image toggling so video thing was not in my mind when I answered the question but if you need more help on that leave a comment. Thanks !

Comment: It works great with the video but I realized I forgot to specify something. There should be two DIFFERENT buttons, not two instances of the same button. I want the other to be a mute/unmute button. Would I need to make an additional toggle function as well as two more classes?

Comment: Is "el" just an arbitrary name or does it mean something? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Only a arbitrary name that receives the current element passed by reference toggle(this).

Answer (score 0):

```
swap : function(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.className = (e.className == 'image1') 
        ? 'image2' 
        : 'image1';        
}
```

You can just make a function that checks the current class and switches it. This is the simplest example in which the 2 classes have different background images. The rest of the logic you could handle in a different function that manages the player's 'state' of playing, paused, etc.